# Bootstrap Table Toggle View with Checkbox

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-table

I am using [Bootstrap Table](https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table). My problem is that when there are checkboxes in my table, table toggle view will be ugly(please see the red rectangle), looks like the second picture below. Can anyone help me how to fix this? Thank you!

[image: Bootstrap Table]
[image: Bootstrap Table Toggle View]

Comment: Add your code to get help on specific part. Without showing your try its very difficult for us to help you..

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the checkboxes in the toggle view using css.

This is how I solved a similar issue:

```
.card-view .title input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: none;
}
```